# Extjs A store update event is fired to late

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I have a situation where I am using an EditorGrid in a window panel.

The window panel has a save button in a bottom toolbar.

In one scenario a user edits the grid and once finished hits the save button without losing focus from the grid prior to the button click.

I have noticed that on IE the event chin is fired differently then on FF or Chrome.

The store update event is fired after the user hits the save button, and the result is that the store is not reflecting the grids latest changes.

I have logged the events on the developer tools of IE and FF:

IE: EVENTS TIME LINE

> LOG: orderGrid1-beforeedit
>
> LOG: store-update
>
> LOG: orderGrid1-afteredit
>
> LOG: orderGrid1-beforeedit
>
> LOG: store-update
>
> LOG: orderGrid1-afteredit
>
> LOG: orderGrid1-beforeedit
>
> LOG: saveButton-click
>
> LOG: store-update  -  NOTICE THAT THIS OCCURRED AFTER THE CLICK EVENT !!!
>
> LOG: orderGrid1-afteredit

FF: EVENTS TIME LINE

> orderGrid1-beforeedit
>
> store-update
>
> orderGrid1-afteredit
>
> orderGrid1-beforeedit
>
> store-update
>
> orderGrid1-afteredit
>
> orderGrid1-beforeedit
>
> store-update
>
> orderGrid1-afteredit
>
> orderGrid1-beforeedit
>
> saveButton-mouseover
>
> store-update - NOTICE THAT THIS EVENT OCCUR RES BEFORE THE BUTTON CLICK EVENT
>
> orderGrid1-afteredit
>
> parseStoreToOrderLines
>
> saveButton-click

Please HELP!!! :)

Comment: Can you provide some code (ideally jsfiddle demo), so we could track this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens probably because edit events are fired within timeout, while click event is fired 
 directly or it's got higher priority in IE. Possible solution to check: set delay for save button (probably even 1ms would be enough). If it won't help you can always disable save button after beforeedit event and enable after afteredit event.

Answer (score 0):

probably because clicking on the button does not cause the edited cell to lose focus right away.

try calling "endEdit()" in the button click handler to work around this problem.

Comment: This is not the case, I have checked this path and it did not work. I believe what Lolo said is the right answer for this problem. Thanks for the help.